# How to retrive json string from Url in Xamarin.forms pcl

Tags: c#, json, http, xamarin, xamarin.forms

For example I have an URL http://www.pizzaboy.de/app/pizzaboy.json
As WebClient is not supported in Xamarin.forms PCL, I went with Xamarin documentation of using web services in forms
and followed this example.

> [Link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/rest/)

I have tried all what I can do to get the json string. But it's not working.

Below code doesn't work for mentioned URL

```
public async Task<List<TodoItem>> RefreshDataAsync ()
        {
        var uri = new Uri ("http://www.pizzaboy.de/app/pizzaboy.json");
        HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient();
    
            var response = await myClient.GetAsync (uri);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
                    Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<TodoItem>> (content);
                }
}
```

Response comes with content set to null .

[Disclaimer: It was network proxy issue which was blocking the above url, above code is just fine]

Comment: is content null or Items is null? it's very different, if content is null then the server returned just nothing, if Items is null then the deserialization failed.

Comment: Thanks I realised it is proxy issue !

Answer (score 5):

Your snippet looked all OK to me and I just gave it a try and it worked like charm for me. I got JSON  string in content variable and I could deserialize it also. Here am sharing the snippet I used.

```
public static async Task RefreshDataAsync ()
    {
        var uri = new Uri ("http://www.pizzaboy.de/app/pizzaboy.json");
        HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient();

        var response = await myClient.GetAsync (uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
            var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<RootObject>> (content);
            Console.WriteLine ("");
        }
    }
```

Here is my definition for the class RootObject I used

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lon { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It ditto what i am trying , Its proxy issue